# How to setup and use VSTS for five user

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfvc

Our office uses VSS as source control. Just come to know that VSTS is free for five users and our team is very small with 5 devs.

I have never use VSTS. so i have few questions. please answer pointwise and with detail along with images if possible.

1. how to create an account for VSTS?
2. how to upload our local project exist on my pc to VSTS
3. how could I send an invitation to other 4 developers in our team, as a result, they can clone our uploaded project on their own pc and start working?

I got [one link which is showing how to Add Local Project to GIT in VSTS](http://www.codeease.com/add-local-project-to-visual-studio-online.html) but I need to know how to add a project to TFVC in VSTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create an account

Go to [VisualStudio.com](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=307137&clcid=0x409), log in using MSA, pick an available account name and register. If you have an Azure subscription and an Azure Active Directory, you can also create the account from the Azure portal, that way you can use your company-account to log on.

### Upload local project

When you create your first project you get to choose whether you want TFVC or Git. Once the project is created, getting your sources in differs depending on your choice.

If you pick TFVC you must [create a local workspace on your machine, copy the sources into that directory, then check them in.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server#place-an-existing-solution-and-code-projects-under-version-control)

### Invite other users

To add other users to VSTS they need to have an MSA account or to be part of your AAD (depending on how you setup your account). [Then go to the Users hub in the VSTS admin panel and add them to your account.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-account-users-from-user-hub#add-users-to-your-vsts-account) The first 5 basic users are free. If users have an MSDN account (pro or higher) they do not count towards the free user limit as VSTS access is included in the subscription.

Comment: Since the VSTS documentation has pretty extensive steps, and since those steps may change in the future I've linked to the guidance on the VSTS docs site. This should be more than sufficient to get going.

Comment: when i will create user then that user will get invitation mail? how could i add user for a specific project? suppose i add user A and i have 3 projects in VSTS. so how could i setup user A will work on project 1. user A will be able to change or add code to the project A. tell me how could i do this ?

Comment: The add user form allows you to pick the project(s) you want to add people to and the role to assign. People will receive an invitation when they're added to the account. My suggestion is to just create an account and try it. You could even create a personal account to just experiment before you create the company account.